# What is the optimized way to store YEAR field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to store some value(year) in `MySQL` `YEAR` field by scraping it from the source site. The data type of `YEAR` field is year(4). I am getting another field(`consumer_details`) containing `YEAR` value from the source site like '2019-95525845-0000'.

So, my question is that what will be the optimized way to store value in `YEAR` field.

Whether it will be to pass the whole value to the `YEAR` column as it will store the first 4 digits and discards the rest of the value.

Or first, extract `YEAR` value from `consumer_details` like '2019' by PHP or Python and then pass it to YEAR` column.

Comment: first, extract YEAR value from consumer_details

Comment: @spyker what is the benefit of doing this over the other.

Comment: Because database is not supposed to do data sanitization for you; Just handle it in application code (PHP etc). What if the data is like `02019-adasd` ? Corrupted/Wrongly truncated data may get entered because of MySQL's own interpretation of things. It is best to keep this logic handling in your end for deterministic behaviour.

Comment: premature optimization is the root of a evil choose the MySQL datatype which best suites your data storage requirements before thinking optimisation.. If you need the store year only choose YEAR do you need a date aswell choose DATE or DATETIME when you also need to store times..  MySQL internally optimizes DATE an DATETYPE datatype storage with some tricks..  And like @MadhurBhaiya already said make sure you provide MySQL with the correct data formats foreach datatype don't trust MySQL into correctly casting it and store it..